# Hiding html table on page loading

Tags: php, html, view, html-table

I have a system, where once a user has logged in, there are two tables. I only want one table to be displayed initially, but I can't seem to get it to hide.
So far I've tried

```
style="display:none;"
```

within the table initiation, and also have tried using javascript to set it on load again, with no luck. My tables are mostly created in php because of using variables etc, and that all works fine, it's just hiding the table that I am having issues with.

```
<table id="mainView" style="width:100%;">
    <!-- php to create table -->
    <?php
         .... code creating table ....
    ?>
</table>
```

And then the second table, which I want hidden on loading

```
<table id="directoryView" style="display:none;">
    <!-- php to create table -->
    <?php
        .... code creating table ....
    ?>
</table>
```

The JS I tried was

```
function initialDisplay()
{
    document.getElementById('mainView').style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById('directoryView').style.display = "none";
}
```

which I called from my main php file using

```
echo "<script> initialDisplay(); </script>";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide **[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**?

Answer (score 0):

**Html:**

```
<body onload="initialDisplay()">

    <table id="mainView" style="width:100%;">
            <!-- php to create table -->
            <?php
                 .... code creating table ....
            ?>
        </table>

        <table id="directoryView" style="display:none;">
            <!-- php to create table -->
            <?php
                .... code creating table ....
            ?>
        </table>
```

**Use JS**

```
 <script>
       function initialDisplay()
      {
    document.getElementById('mainView').style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById('directoryView').style.display = "none";
      }       
        </script>
```

Comment: Don't guide user to advise new thing. You need to try only with `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**In Javascript**

```
<body onload="initialDisplay()">

        <table id="mainView" style="width:100%;" border="1">
                <!-- php to create table -->
                  <tr><td>test content1</td></tr>
            </table>

            <table id="directoryView">
                <!-- php to create table -->
               <tr><td>test content2</td></tr>
            </table>
</body>

     <script>
    function initialDisplay()
          {
        document.getElementById('mainView').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('directoryView').style.display = "none";
          }  
     </script>
```

**In jquery**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body >

        <table id="mainView" style="width:100%;" border="1">
                <!-- php to create table -->
                  <tr><td>test content1</td></tr>
            </table>

            <table id="directoryView">
                <!-- php to create table -->
               <tr><td>test content2</td></tr>
            </table>
</body>

     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#mainView").show();
     $("#directoryView").hide();

     });
     </script>
```